# Image is uploaded but corrupted after I uploaded image on s3, what did I do wrong?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've created an api to upload images to my s3 bucket, but currently the images which I upload to s3 seem to be unreadable so I'm guessing they're corrupted?

Here is my code below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3= new AWS.S3()
const crypto = require("crypto")

const sha1 = data => {
    return crypto.createHash("sha1").update(data).digest("hex")
}

const getFile = (ext, buffer, type) => {
    let encryptedFileName = sha1(new Buffer(new Date().toString()))
    //let timeBasedFileName = new Date().valueOf()


    let fileName = encryptedFileName+'.'+ext
    let bucketPath = "bucketname/folder/"+type //eg: bucket1/animals/fish
    let fileFullPath = bucketPath+"/"+fileName //eg: bucket1/animals/fish/salmon.jpg

    let params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucket',
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: ext==='jpg'||ext==='jpeg'?'image/jpeg':'image/'+ext,
        Key: fileName
    }

    let uploadFile = {
        size: buffer.toString('ascii').length,
        type: ext==='jpg'||ext==='jpeg'?'image/jpeg':'image/'+ext,
        name: fileName,
        full_path: fileFullPath
    }

    return {params,uploadFile}
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        let base64String = event.base64String
        let ext = base64String.substring("data:image/".length, base64String.indexOf(";base64"))
        if (ext===null || (ext!=='jpg' && ext!=='jpeg' && ext!=='gif' && ext!=='png')) {return context.fail('Base64 string is not a supported file type.')}

        //pass base64 string into buffer
        let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64')

        let file = getFile(ext, buffer, event.type)
        //callback(null, 'working fine')
        let params = file.params
        s3.putObject(params, function(err,data) {
            // example response: {"filename":"0242CCB0-CE2E-4C75-A02E-FC054DA9E743.png","status":1,"message":"save success"}
            let response = {"statusCode": 400, "filename": "", status: 0, message: "save fail"}
            if (err) {callback(err, null)}

            response.statusCode=200
            response.filename=file.uploadFile.name
            response.status=1
            response.message="save success"
            callback(null, response)
        })
}
```

I'm basically converting a base64 image string into a buffer & uploading it.
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: The problem is the missing content type in `s3.putObject`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721634/upload-image-into-s3-bucket-using-api-gateway-lambda-funnction/55777760#55777760

add `ContentType: ext==='jpg'||ext==='jpeg'?'image/jpg':'image/'+ext` in your `params`

Comment: @jogold I've added the `ContentType` in my `params`, currently I'm able to open the image file in another tab but all I'm seeing is a square box. I've tried uploading other images and I'm still seeing a square box. Anything I missed?

Comment: Can you share a public link?

Comment: @jogold I'm not sure if I'm allowed to share but here is a screenshot of what I got, https://imgur.com/9oigRmi

Comment: It seems llke the base64 string is not a valid image? Also `Bucket: bucketPath` is not correct, you need to pass only the bucket name in there. + the right MIME type for jpg/jpeg is image/jpeg not image/jpg

Comment: @jogold the bucketPath is pointing to 2 folders deep inside my bucket, setting it to the bucket name would upload to the main bucket directory itself (just tried). But that's not the issue, currently I'm still getting the square box even if I used my bucket name in the `params`. Updated my post. And I've updated the mime type for jpeg, but the pic I was uploading was png anyway, so any ideas about this square box issue?

Comment: I don't see anything in the code, it must be something with the inputted base64 string? Maybe try to log the `event` and double check in CloudWatch that you are receiving what you expect?