# AWS S3 - Allow public to view HTML files

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I am looking to allow public users to view HTML files located on an AWS S3 bucket on their browser.  These HTML files are created and uploaded to my S3 bucket via node.js, and a URL linking to the file is generated.

I am using this method to upload the HTML files:

```
s3.upload({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: "HTMLFiles/file.HTML",
    Body: fileStream,
    ACL: 'public-read'
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
    if (data) {
        console.log("Success: ", data.Location);
    }
}).on('httpUploadProgress', event => {
    console.log(`Uploaded ${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
});
```

When the script is run, the generated URL looks something like this:

https://bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/HTMLFiles/file.html

(Obviously this is only an example URL and not the actual URL)

When a user goes to this URL, instead of viewing the HTML file, the browser instead downloads the file.

How can I specify that this file is meant to be loaded on the browser and viewed, not downloaded?

Comment: You may also be able to accomplish this by enabling website hosting on the bucket; we regularly upload files to S3 using a very similar method and we do not pass the ContentType, and they are served directly from the S3 bucket, as HTML files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the content type is missing so the browser doesn't know that your file should be interpreted as HTML.

Please add `ContentType: 'text/html'` in the parameters passed to `s3.upload`.

See also the explanations and links given in [Upload Image into S3 bucket using Api Gateway, Lambda funnction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721634/upload-image-into-s3-bucket-using-api-gateway-lambda-funnction/55777760#55777760)