# Internal server error - when upload base64 through aws lambda/api gateway/s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload image to s3 through aws lambda.
I am using the code in below url in Lambda and I only changed variable fileFullPath and Bucket value .
[Upload Image into S3 bucket using Api Gateway, Lambda funnction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721634/upload-image-into-s3-bucket-using-api-gateway-lambda-funnction)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const moment = require('moment');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const sha1 = require('sha1');
const multipart = require('parse-multipart');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    let request = event.body;

    // get the request
    let base64String = request.base64String;

    // pass the base64 string into a buffer
    let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64');

    let fileMime = fileType(buffer);

    // check if the base64 encoded string is a file
    if (fileMime === null) {
        return context.fail('The string supplied is not a file type');
    }

    let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer);
    // let file = getFile(fileMime, parts);
    let params = file.params;

    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    // putObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        }

        // if the file object is uploaded successfully to 
        // s3 then you can get your full url
        console.log('File URL', file.full_path + JSON.stringify(data));
        callback(null, data);

    });
}

let getFile = function (fileMime, buffer) {

    // get the file extension
    let fileExt = fileMime.ext;
    let hash = sha1(new Buffer(new Date().toString()));
    let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    let filePath = hash + '/';
    let fileName = now + '.' + fileExt;
    let fileFullName = filePath + fileName;
    let fileFullPath = 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucket-name/images/' + fileFullName;

    console.log('fileFullPath' + fileFullPath);
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-name',
        Key: fileFullPath,
        // 'this is simply the filename and the extension, e.g fileFullName + fileExt',
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: fileMime.mime
    };

    let uploadFile = {
        size: buffer.toString('ascii').length,
        type: fileMime.mime,
        name: fileName,
        full_path: fileFullPath
    }

    return {
        'params': params,
        'uploadFile': uploadFile
    }
}
```

[image]

Execution role for this lambda function:
[image]

In API Gateway, I only create the resource and method 'POST' and have nothing set in method request section.
I've made a test for this POST method but Internal server error occur:
[image]

Update: current error got from cloudwatch

```
The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
```

Comment: Have you checked cloudwatch logs for any lambda errors?

Comment: Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'moment'"

Comment: So you know why it fails. I don't know what is `moment` module, but it seems you are not providing it with your lambda package or in a lambda layer.

Comment: should I install the dependency? Because in the stackoverflow post I followed , it uses the same code

Comment: They may have the same code, but the dependencies provided as a lambda layer or bundled with the main code.

Comment: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined

Comment: This is current error. Is the problem of my body request?

Comment: The first argument to what function?

Comment: Update: TypeError-filetype is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who just start using or learing aws lambda,
You can just go to the cloudwatch and watch the logs,
which contain the actual error and the log of "console.log(xxx)"